# How to track zoom location?

Tags: premiere, after-effects, tracking

I'm trying to track an object. How can I keep the tracked object centered when I zoom? I have After Effects and Premiere Pro, but I prefer a Premiere Pro solution if it's possible. It's much faster for my editing workflow.